# Skipping before action in base controller does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

It works only if I add the `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` in AddressController. Anyone know why? I am using rails `4.1.8`

```
class App::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token # This does not work
end

class App::V1::AddressController < App::BaseController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token # This works
  before_action :require_auth!

  def create
  end
end
```

I would like to avoid "Can't verify CSRF token" since this is API controller and I am using token in header to auth requests.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the skip_before_action?

Comment: Avoid "Can't verify CSRF token" since this is API controller and I am using token in header to auth requests.

Comment: Is there an error message that occurs when you put it in `App::BaseController`? If so, what is it?

Comment: Can you post your verify_authenticity_token and require_auth! Methods?

Comment: This is what I am trying to do http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, I had `skip_before_action` before `protect_from_forgery`, reversing that order fixed it.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```